# Transposing the key using jfugue - Some questions concerning Jfugue

Tags: jfugue

I have a couple of questions concerning JFugue (5, the beta version).

- From *The complete guide to JFugue*, it is mentioned that depending on the Key Signature in the pattern, JFugue interprets the note value. As an example, in the case of an F-major key, B would be automatically translated to B-flat, unless we write "Bn" instead.
  The question is that if we are dealing with an F major key and write "Bb" how would JFugue interpret it ? As "Bbb" or as a "Bb" note ?
- My second question is about transposing Keys in JFugue. 
  What is the fastest way of doing so ?

Thank you for your help, 
Best Regards, 
Hussein Hammoud.

Comment: These are both excellent questions, thank you! I'll do my best to answer them, but unfortunately I can't do it today.

Comment: Oh And I have another question, JFugue 5 is giving me an error when I play a pattern containing a numerical value of a note (example: C5 corresponds to [60]). That is not the case in JFugue4. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: For that last one, use 60 without the brackets. JFugue 5 does away with brackets except in cases where the stuff inside the bracket is a string to look up in a dictionary (e.g., "T[Allegro]" or "I[Piano]"). Numbers are just numbers and do not need brackets in JFugue 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the first part of your question: In the key of F-Major, Bb is played like Bb, the same as B itself when played in F-Major. Here's a program that tests this:

```
StaccatoParser parser = new StaccatoParser();
DiagnosticParserListener dpl = new DiagnosticParserListener();
parser.addParserListener(dpl);
Pattern pattern = new Pattern("KEY:Cmaj B Bn Bb   KEY:FMaj B Bn Bb");
parser.parse(pattern);
```

And its output (note that MIDI Note 70 is Bb and MIDI Note 71 is B):

```
Before parsing starts
Key signature parsed: key = 0  scale = 1
Note parsed: value = 71  duration = 0.25  onVelocity = 64  offVelocity = 64
Note parsed: value = 71  duration = 0.25  onVelocity = 64  offVelocity = 64
Note parsed: value = 70  duration = 0.25  onVelocity = 64  offVelocity = 64
Key signature parsed: key = 5  scale = 1
Note parsed: value = 70  duration = 0.25  onVelocity = 64  offVelocity = 64
Note parsed: value = 71  duration = 0.25  onVelocity = 64  offVelocity = 64
Note parsed: value = 70  duration = 0.25  onVelocity = 64  offVelocity = 64
After parsing finished
```

Answer to the second part of your question: I'm not sure there's a decent answer right now. But you have inspired me to write a `transpose()` method on the `Pattern` class. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your answers ! This was really helpful. I am currently trying to write the "transpose()" method and I will send it to you if it ends up working without any bugs. I appreciate your response :D
Best Regards,
Hussein.